# Getting an "unexpected keyword_end" for if/else statements

Tags: ruby

```
def load x
    @maze_string = x
    @maze_string_split = x.chars.to_a
    string_counter = 0
    y=@height
    x=@width

    (0..(y*2+1)).each do |n|
        if @maze_string_split[counter] !=1
            puts "Error in given string, wall expected"
        else
            @maze_array[n] = @maze_string_split[counter]
            counter++
        end

        (0..(x*2)).each do |m|
            if n==0 || n==(y*2+1) || m==(x*2)
                if @maze_string_split[counter] != 1
                    puts "Error in given string"
                else
                    @maze_array[n][m] = @maze_string_split[counter]
                    counter++
                end
            else
                @maze_array[n][m] = @maze_string_split[counter]
                counter++
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I am getting the error in the title on the "end" statements at the conclusion of each if/else block. All seems well, but the errors remain. I tried looking to see if anyone else had this problem, but I can't find anything specific to my problem

Comment: For next time, it's useful to post the full backtrace of the errors are they give useful hints of where the errors are coming from. In this case, each of the `unexpected keyword_end` errors were coming from each of the `if` statements and each of them had the `counter++` issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby does not have a `++` or `--` operator.

Ruby will not parse these out correctly in that is the reason you're getting an `unexpected keyword_end`, it is expecting another operand.

Replace the

`counter++` with `counter += 1`

Also, note that your variable is not called `counter` but `string_counter`

Comment: Thanks! I keep making this mistake